# "unpivot" data from Excel

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, unpivot

I need to clean up some ugly data. What I have is similar to

```
ID,someFields,Supplier,Supplier_1,Supplier_2,Price,Price_1,Price_2,Weight; Weight_1,Weight_2
```

and so forth. Fields are named up to _9 and there are actually 8 different such fields named _1 to _9. Of course Price_1 is for Supplier_1 and so forth.

I would now like to unpivot to

```
ID,someFields,Supplier,Price,Weight
```

by duplicating ID and somefields.
An important note is that those _1 to _9 fields can be null, in fact most of them are.

Tools I have.
Excel
MS Access
could (mis)use oracle schema I have access to...

I found this
[How to simulate UNPIVOT in Access 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255423/how-to-simulate-unpivot-in-access-2010)

However that also multiplies rows that only have 1 Supplier.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union query.

```
 SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM
  (SELECT ID,someFields,Supplier,Price,Weight FROM Table
   WHERE SomeField Is Not Null
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ID,someFields1,Supplier1,Price1,Weight1 FROM Table
   WHERE SomeField1 Is Not Null
   <...>)
```