# Need advice on working with a poorly designed employee event attendance database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I asked a few questions on Friday relating to some problems I am having with an Acess database. The database tracks the attendance of about 5000 employees at about 200 training events over the last 10 or so years.

Currently there is a master table where each event is designated as a field, and in each row a checkbox marks whether that specific employee attended that specific event. There is also a table for each individual event that lists which employees attended that event.

There is also a form that can be used to create new records for employees or view/modify existing employee records.

I'm trying to create a dynamic list on this form that shows which events the selected employee has attended.

Can anyone offer any advice on how I could solve this problem?

Comment: Please include the DDL (data definition language) for the tables in question. If relationships are not obvious please include descriptions on how those relationships exist.

Comment: Assuming you won't be adding any more events, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255423/how-to-simulate-unpivot-in-access-2010

Comment: Please don't ask the same question repeatedly. If you are not receiving satisfactory answers to an existing question then edit that question to improve it.