# How to find the intersection of a row and column in a table and put that data into another table

Tags: ms-access

I am a novice at Access. If there is a simple answer, then please accept my apologies up front.

I am working on a database for my office. Each year salary tables are put out that shows the salary for a GSx step x.  I am trying to figure out how to update salary information for each employee at the beginning of each year.

I also have the employee table that has a field that shows what grade and a field that shows what step each employee is as well as a field that shows what their annual salary is.

Is there a way for me to update the employee records each year by telling access to go look at the salary table and finding the intersection of a row and column to pull the salary in based on the grade and step fields in the employee table?

Or, in other words, can I get access to go find the intersection of GS 9 row at the step 8 column? Then take that specific salary and "paste" it into the employee record?  It would save a LOT of time and effort to be able to get the software to do it vice having a person do it.

Again. sorry if this is a question that should be easy to answer...I am beating my head against the wall right now.

Answer (score 0):

So before answering your question, I think the better question is, why are you duplicating data throughout your DBMS? From what you make it sound like, there are two tables:

*SALARIES*

```
SALARY_ID | SALARY_GRADE | SALARY_STEP | SALARY_AMOUNT
```

*EMPLOYEES*

```
EMPLOYEE_ID | GRADE | STEP | SALARY
```

[Database normalization rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) state that you should try to reduce redundancy as much as possible in your relation/table structure. Additionally, you should also strive to NOT store calculated fields wherever possible, only retaining the primitives.

Therefore, I would remove the salary field from the *EMPLOYEES* table and restructure it as follows:

*EMPLOYEES*

```
EMPLOYEE_ID | GRADE | STEP
```

And when you need the **SALARY_AMOUNT** value, simply `JOIN` the *EMPLOYEE* on **GRADE** and **STEP**. The only additional data that may be required in the *EMPLOYEES* table is if there would be any additional salary amount (bonus, raise, etc.) that does not apply to all *EMPLOYEE*s.

Comment: Guess Tony should have added more information about un-pivoting tables. As Sarah seems to have the salary steps as columns and the grads as rows, the amount being in the intersection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255423/how-to-simulate-unpivot-in-access-2010

Comment: Good call - apologies as was hard to visualize without code/formatted text. If you cannot un-pivot as my astute colleague y4cine mentioned, you may need to resort to a built-in application to be able to dynamically read the employee's step, then use that as the field name in your selection query.