# Query only pulling in output from one column instead of all columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I actually first tried doing this in excel with a bunch of nested vlookups and encountered the same error so I tried doing it in access thinking I would resolve the problem, but I get the exact same issue.

All I am trying to do is join two tables by an inner join with 1 column in the one table and one of many columns in the other table (and I want the output to be (the one that is causing my issue) to be one particular column. Here is a small sample of the data and what I tried to get followed by my query.

Table 1:

```
Search    unique

gloves    5000
beaker    3000
tea       1000
timer     2000
```

Table 2:

```
Name   Field1   Field 2    Field3 ....
gloves hello    goodbye
Time   timer    clock
hi     tea
```

when I do an inner join I get:

```
gloves 5000
```

instead of getting:

```
gloves 5000
tea    1000
timer  2000
```

Hence it is only joining it on the 1st column, no idea why? Here is the Query I wrote in Access:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product.Category, Analytics.Unique
FROM Product INNER JOIN Analytics ON IIF(Analytics.Search = Product.Category 
Is Not Null,Analytics.Search = Product.Category, IIF(Analytics.Search = 
Product.Field4 Is Not Null, Analytics.Search = Product.Field4, 
IIF(Analytics.Search = Product.Field5 Is Not Null, Analytics.Search = 
Product.Field5, IIF(Analytics.Search = Product.Field6 Is Not Null, 
Analytics.Search = Product.Field6, IIF(Analytics.Search = Product.Field7 Is 
Not Null, Analytics.Search = Product.Field7, IIF(Analytics.Search = 
Product.Field8 Is Not Null, Analytics.Search = Product.Field8,  
IIF(Analytics.Search = Product.Field9 Is Not Null, Analytics.Search = 
Product.Field9, IIF(Analytics.Search = Product.Field10 Is Not Null, 
Analytics.Search = Product.Field10))))))));
```

Comment: I think you need to [UNPIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255423/how-to-simulate-unpivot-in-access-2010) your Table2, and then join on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your expressions are not testing what you think they are testing. The partial expression

```
Analytics.Search = Product.Category Is Not Null
```

is equivalent to

```
(Analytics.Search = Product.Category) Is Not Null
```

In other words, testing whether a boolean value is not null. And boolean values never are null.

You probably want something more like this:

```
... ON Analytics.Search = IIF(Product.Category Is Not Null, Product.Category, 
                          IIF(Product.Field4 Is Not Null, Product.Field4, ...
```

Comment: I just tried what you are doing and still have the same problem, am I missing something: SELECT DISTINCT Product.Category, Analytics.Unique
FROM Product LEFT JOIN Analytics ON Analytics.Search = IIF(Product.Category Is Not Null, Product.Category, IIF(Product.Field4 Is Not Null, Product.Field4, IIF(Product.Field5 Is Not Null, Product.Field5)));

Comment: Are you sure your fields are really NULL and not just empty strings?

Comment: yea I think that could be a problem, what do I do if they are empty strings?

Comment: You can check for both:  `IIF(Product.Category Is Not Null and Product.Category <> ""`

Comment: Thanks! I got this to work but now I found out I need to update what I have to do in this assignment and I can't get the update to work so I will create a new question now, reference this one as well.

Comment: @ Ross Presser, would you please be able to check out my other question, I really like how you answered this one so I think you do a very good job answering questions in a coherent manner, Thank you!: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553712/selecting-partial-string-matches-full-words-only

Answer (score 0):

```
select table2.search, table1.unique
from table1 t 
inner join table2 t2 on t2.name = t.search
inner join table2 t3 on t3.field1 = t.search
inner join table2 t4 on t4.field2 = t.search
inner join table2 t5 on t5.field3 = t.search
```

Comment: This won't work at all. You've got 4 aliases - t2, t3, t4, t5 - and none of them are table2. The select clause won't be able to find table2.search