# Abbreviating a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I do have the next query to be run in Access, It does well, but as you can see, there is a similitude in the first 3 `SELECT`. I want to know if there is the possibility to optimize this, since I will be adding houndreds of 
`c`'s.

[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB3KD.png)

```
SELECT id, IIF(c1>=0, c1, ) AS positive, IIF(c1<0, c1, ) AS negative  FROM tblcostos 

UNION ALL

SELECT id, IIF(c2>=0, c2, ) AS positive, IIF(c2<0, c2, ) AS negative  FROM tblcostos 

UNION ALL 

SELECT id, IIF(c3>=0, c3, ) AS positive, IIF(c3<0, c3, ) AS negative  FROM tblcostos

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'sum  positivo + negative' AS id, SUM(c1 + c2 + c3) AS positive, "" AS negative FROM tblcostos

ORDER BY id;
```

[Query Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo7Sc.png)

I require the final table to be shown like this, because I'll end up with a .txt with that format

Comment: Sample data and the results you're trying to obtain from that data would be helpful here.

Comment: Table not `Normalized` and you are limited to 255 fields in a table/query.

Comment: don't add hundred's of "c's" as new columns. SQL is "row oriented" and your queries will be MUCH easier if you change to using extra rows instead of extra columns. research `normalization`

Comment: Sounds like you want to run [UNPIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255423/how-to-simulate-unpivot-in-access-2010) - there is no other way in Access than lots of UNION clauses.

Comment: Thanks for those advices, Normalization of tables and "row oriented"

Answer (score -2):

I dont know what you try to archive but it seems like you want so sort your table by the ID and split them in positive and negative and sum all.

```
'Order after ID
SELECT ID FROM tblcosts ORDER BY ID DESC 'or mabye ASC

'Positive and Negative columns
SELECT ID, IIF( ID > 0, ID, Null) AS Positive, IIF( ID < 0, ID, Null) AS Negative FROM tblcosts ORDERBY ID DESC

'Sum
SELECT SUM(ID) AS SummeID FROM tblcosts
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to split the IDs but all other columns.