# pivot SQL query access

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

When writing a query in MS Access my results return as such

```
MONTH   Field_Off_Code  test    test2   test3   test4   test5   Test6
1/1/2018    879 10669   11950   0.892803    8962    10452   0.857444
2/1/2018    870 10761   10819   0.994639    9097    9616    0.946027
```

However I would like them to return Like this

```
MONTH   MONTH
1/1/2018    2/1/2018
10669   10761
11950   10819
0.892803347 0.994639061
8962    9097
10452   9616
0.857443551 0.946027454
```

Can someone suggest the correct SQL tried using the crosstab function but no luck.

Comment: Your desired result is not in relational form.  The columns do not have uniform types.

Comment: This is not PIVOT (rows to columns) but UNPIVOT (columns to rows). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255423/how-to-simulate-unpivot-in-access-2010

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate UNPIVOT in Access 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255423/how-to-simulate-unpivot-in-access-2010)