# How to show yes/no fields as values in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm new to SQL and having a hard time to query the following table
[image]

into something like this

[image]

I know UNION is involved here but I can't seem to make this work. Kindly help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate UNPIVOT in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255423/how-to-simulate-unpivot-in-access)

Answer (score 0):

You may try something along the lines of the following:

```
SELECT
    RESP_ID,
    RESP_LVL
FROM
(
    SELECT RESP_ID, 1 AS RESP_LVL FROM yourTable WHERE LEVEL1 = 'Y' UNION ALL
    SELECT RESP_ID, 2 AS RESP_LVL FROM yourTable WHERE LEVEL2 = 'Y' UNION ALL
    SELECT RESP_ID, 3 AS RESP_LVL FROM yourTable WHERE LEVEL3 = 'Y' UNION ALL
    SELECT RESP_ID, 4 AS RESP_LVL FROM yourTable WHERE LEVEL4 = 'Y' UNION ALL
    SELECT RESP_ID, 5 AS RESP_LVL FROM yourTable WHERE LEVEL5 = 'Y' UNION ALL
    SELECT RESP_ID, 6 AS RESP_LVL FROM yourTable WHERE LEVEL6 = 'Y' UNION ALL
    SELECT RESP_ID, 7 AS RESP_LVL FROM yourTable WHERE LEVEL7 = 'Y'
) t
ORDER BY
    RESP_ID,
    RESP_LVL;
```

I am assuming here that your checkboxes are backed by a `CHAR(1)` field, which would have the values of `Y` or `N`.  If not, then you would have to change slightly the logic I used above.