# Get latest date from 4 columns function

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following query "qryE".

```
Equipment   E1_45J          E2_45J         E3_45J      E4_45J
400         2019-03-25      2019-10-07  
401         2019-04-01      2019-10-23  
402         2019-02-14      2019-08-25                 2019-11-11
403         2019-02-11      2019-09-05     2019-11-25
```

I made a function to return the latest value between these 4 columns:

```
Function getmaxdate(dteDate1 As Date, dteDate2 As Date, dteDate3 As Date, dteDate4 As Date) As Date

    Dim dteMaxDate As Date

    dteMaxDate = dteDate1
    Debug.Print dteDate2
    If IsDate(dteDate2) Then
        If dteDate2 > dteMaxDate Then dteMaxDate = dteDate2
    If IsDate(dteDate3) Then
        If dteDate3 > dteMaxDate Then dteMaxDate = dteDate3
    If IsDate(dteDate4) Then
        If dteDate4 > dteMaxDate Then dteMaxDate = dteDate4
    getmaxdate = dteMaxDate

End Function
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
 Equipment   45J          
 400         2019-10-07  
 401         2019-10-23  
 402         2019-11-11
 403         2019-11-25
```

However, when I run the query with 45J:

```
getmaxdate([E1_45J],[E2_45J],[E3_45J],[E4_45J])
```

I'm getting *Data type mismatch in criteria expression.*

I tried to force the format of the values of my query with:

```
45J: getmaxdate(Format([E1_45J], "yyyy/mm/dd"),Format([E2_45J], "yyyy/mm/dd"),Format([E3_45J], "yyyy/mm/dd"),Format([E4_45J], "yyyy/mm/dd"))
```

However, I'm still getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are blank values, access is a stickler for data types, and null dates are problematic in my experience. You will need to check each for blanks and then skip it.

Comment: Ideally you want one column for date, but if you can't change the table design, you could use a union all to unpivot the data and use then use max function in the outer query.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255423/how-to-simulate-unpivot-in-access

Comment: In addition to above suggest SQL answer - for a potential pure VBA solution - http://allenbrowne.com/func-09.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're getting a *type mismatch* because you're passing a `Null` to a `Date` parameter, and you can't do that.

Change the function's signature to accept `Variant` values instead of `Date` - a `Variant` can hold a `Null` value.

With all parameters defined `As Date`, the `IsDate` function can only ever return `True`.

I'd suggest not assuming `date1` is a valid date, and default the "max date" to `CDate(0)`: if the record has any dates in it, it'll be greater than that.

Careful to close your `If...End If` blocks, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using SQL on qryE, my table is `tblTesting`, so you would change that.

```
select equipment,MAX(d) as mxDate from
(
SELECT 
equipment,
E1_45J as d from tblTesting 
UNION
SELECT 
equipment,
E2_45J as d  from tblTesting 
UNION
SELECT 
equipment,
E3_45J as d  from tblTesting
UNION
SELECT 
equipment,
E4_45J as d  from tblTesting
)
group by equipment
```