# Convert columns to rows and get the sum of checkboxes in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an Access database that has checkboxes in on of the tables.  I need to get a Sum of the checkboxes but, I want to convert the checkbox columns into rows instead of columns.

Here is an example of how it appears in the table:

```
 Name         DND  Other  CAP   SAP   DAP   EXP
Person One    -1    -1    NULL  NULL  -1    -1
Person Two    NULL  -1    -1     -1   NULL  NULL
Person Three  NULL  -1    -1    NULL  NULL  NUll
```

Here is how I want the report to display the data:

```
 Discharge  Count
    DND        1
    Other      3
    CAP        2
    SAP        1
    DAP        1
    EXP        1
```

I tried using a Case statement but, it didn't come out correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [union query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361) and check for *Null*:

```sql
Select 
    T.Discharge, Abs(Sum(T.[Count])) As DischargeCount
From 
    (Select "DND" As Discharge, [DND] Is Not Null As [Count] From YourTable
    Union ALL
    Select "Other" As Discharge, [Other] Is Not Null As [Count] From YourTable
    Union ALL
    Select "CAP" As Discharge, [CAP] Is Not Null As [Count] From YourTable
    Union ALL
    Select "SAP" As Discharge, [SAP] Is Not Null As [Count] From YourTable
    Union ALL
    Select "DAP" As Discharge, [DAP] Is Not Null As [Count] From YourTable
    Union ALL
    Select "EXP" As Discharge, [EXP] Is Not Null As [Count] From YourTable) As T
Group By
    T.Discharge
```

Comment: Thanks. Both were helpful but, this was even better.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'DND' AS Discharge, COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM tbl WHERE DND = -1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Other' AS Discharge, COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM tbl WHERE Other = -1
UNION ALL
```

etc.

I don't think there is an easier way.

This is air code, not sure if you need a `GROUP BY` clause.

Compare [How to simulate UNPIVOT in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255423/how-to-simulate-unpivot-in-access)